# Tips on speeding up django views?

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

I am trying to do some data analysis for a company(sales, stock, yearly progression and so on). However, I'm finding that the calculation time is enormous(almost 1 minute for a single page with a single line graph). I'ce already checked the queries and they take around 2 seconds(still a lot, but whatever). Using django-debug-toolbar, I've seen that request rendering(which I suppose is the page's view) takes around 50 seconds. Do you guys have any idea of how I could Speed that up?

This is the code:

Main function for the graph:

```
def get_data_progression(years):
    result = {}

    for year in reversed(years):
        result[year] = {
            "uscite": 0,
            "entrate": 0,
            "magazzino": {
                "val": 0,
                "nbr": 0
            },
            "valorizzazione": 0,
            "months": []
        }
        for i in range(1, 13):
            entrate = 0#get_entrate_month(year, i)
            uscite = 0#get_uscite_month(year, i)
            m_val, m_nb = get_magazzino_month(year, i)
            result[year]["months"].append({
                "entrate": entrate,
                "uscite": uscite,
                "magazzino": m_val,
            })
            result[year]["entrate"] = entrate
            result[year]["uscite"] = uscite
            result[year]["magazzino"]["val"] = m_val
            result[year]["magazzino"]["nbr"] = m_nb
        result[year]["valorizzazione"] = result[year]["magazzino"]["val"] + result[year]["entrate"] - result[year]["uscite"]
    return result
```

And this is the function I am trying to optimize. I've left out irrelevant parts: what you see is what takes 50 seconds to load:

```
def get_magazzino_month(year, month):
    from magazzino.models import ddt_in_item, omaggi_item, inventario_item
    from corrispettivi.models import corrispettivi_item, corrispettivi
    from fatture.models import fatture_item, fatture, fatture_laboratori_item
    from prodotti.models import prodotti
    qt = 0
    val = 0

    products = prodotti.objects.all()

    for prod in products:
        fats = fatture_laboratori_item.objects.order_by("-id_fattura__data").filter(id_prodotti=prod, id_fattura__data__year=year).first()
        prezzo = (fats.costo_acquisto/fats.quantita - ((fats.costo_acquisto/fats.quantita) * fats.sconto / 100)) if fats else prod.costo_acquisto
return val, qt
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are importing your libraries within the function? This may be adding to your overhead.

Comment: I think this question is more about speeding up Python than speeding up Django views.